# Convert String to Date in ADF Pipeline

Tags: u-sql

I am very new to Usql scripts and need to convert my Date field which is coming from CSV file as string in my blob storage.
My Blob is linked to DB table which contains a Date field. DB is not accepting String '02/02/2016' into DB date field.

In DataFactory Pipeline, how can I convert String '02/02/2016' to Date in DB (Blob -> Azure SQL DB).

Comment: You make reference to Data Factory Pipelines and U-SQL, which are different things.  What are you trying to use the date values in the CSV for?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are trying to convert this value within your U-SQL script, you can do so using the C# [`DateTime.ParseExact`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/parsing-datetime) function once you have `EXTRACT`ed your data from the CSV as a `string`:

```
@data =
    EXTRACT YourDateValue string
    USING Extractors.Text();

@format =
    SELECT DateTime.ParseExact(YourDateValue
                              ,"dd/MM/yyyy"
                              ,CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
                              ) AS YourDateValue
    FROM @data;
```

---

If possible however, you would be better served changing the format of the `Date` values that are stored in your CSV files.

Comment: Thanks Dave, I managed to do this using U-SQL now. But can I also be able achieve without using U-SQL script in my ADF? Like Changing the MetaData somewhere in-between moving my data from Blob to Azure SQL DB?

Comment: @Harsh You cannot do these kind of transformations directly in ADF, but SSIS integration is available with data factory. Using it using do the transformations between source and sink